# How do I use reflection to get a class's properties in PHP?

Tags: php, reflection

I'm trying to use reflection to get details about an arbitrary object, but I'm getting conflicting and confusing feedback.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;

print '$dom: '; print_r($dom);

print 'get_object_vars(): '; print_r(get_object_vars($dom));

$r = new ReflectionObject($dom);
print '$r->getProperties(): '; print_r($r->getProperties());
print '$r->getStaticProperties(): '; print_r($r->getStaticProperties());
print '$r->hasProperty("doctype"): '; var_dump($r->hasProperty("doctype"));
print '$r->getProperty("doctype"): '; var_dump($r->getProperty("doctype"));
```

Here's what I get on **PHP 7.4** when I run the above:

```
$dom: DOMDocument Object
(
    [doctype] => (object value omitted)
    [implementation] => (object value omitted)
    [documentElement] => (object value omitted)
    [actualEncoding] => 
    [encoding] => 
    [xmlEncoding] => 
<30 lines snipped>
)
get_object_vars(): Array
(
)
$r->getProperties(): Array
(
)
$r->getStaticProperties(): Array
(
)
$r->hasProperty("doctype"): bool(true)
$r->getProperty("doctype"): PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Property doctype does not exist ...
```

So basically,

- `print_r()` (and `var_dump()`) dump useful information **just fine**
- `get_object_vars` gives me an **empty result**
- `ReflectionObject->getProperties` gives me an **empty result**
- `ReflectionObject->hasProperty()` tells me that a property `print_r()` found **does**, indeed, **exist**...
- ...aaaaand `ReflectionObject->getProperty()` to get the same property **throws a ReflectionException**. I'd *like* to invoke `ReflectionProperty->setAccessible(true)` in case it helps, but PHP is throwing *in the process* of getting a `ReflectionProperty` I could call that method on in the first place.

An understanding of what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: [There used to be a similar bug.](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48527) This may be another one. Though I'm not sure how the reflection API is supposed to interact with these internal classes in general, since they are not purely PHP classes (they are defined in C).

Comment: Oh yay. Thanks, I was wondering what was going on. I'll *sigh* file a bug then. Annoyingly there does not seem to be a workaround, so it'll be a few years **after** this is fixed before people will finally be able to use 3rd-party debug/dumping routines (I use my own) with XML. :(

Comment: [The closest one is reported here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=77685)

Comment: Another day, another bug entered into the tracker. Here it is: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=79065

Comment: @Rain: thanks very much, stumbled on that link early on but then lost it and nearly didn't add it to the bug :)